# ERROR---Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I'm developing weather application  which is working fine in browsers.
But when I try to deploy in my android phone it is not working fine and it is throwing error. XML response is null. please help me.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Calling Web Service from jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='xmlObject.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.8.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCallWebService").click(function (event) {
                alert('click' + $("#cityName").val());

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather",true);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
                    {   
                        var myXML=xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        alert("Response XML in getWeatherInformation : ");
                        alert(myXML);                                                                        

                        var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);                                                
                        var body=JSON.stringify(json.Body[0]);
                        var result = json.Body[0].GetWeatherResponse[0].GetWeatherResult[0].Text;

                        var myXML2=XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result);                        
                        var json2 = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(myXML2);                       
                        var body2=json2;
                        var location=body2.Location[0].Text;
                        var time=body2.Time[0].Text;
                        var temperature=body2.Temperature[0].Text;
                        var pressure=body2.Pressure[0].Text;
                        alert("location"+location+"..."+time+".."+temperature+".."+pressure);

                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                var xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                            '<soap:Body>'+
                            '<GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">'+
                            '<CityName>'+ $("#cityName").val() +'</CityName>'+
                            '<CountryName>India</CountryName>'+
                            '</GetWeather>'+
                            '</soap:Body>'+
                            '</soap:Envelope>';

                alert("Request XML : ");
                alert(xml);
                xmlhttp.send(xml);  

                            });

        });



        function processSuccess(data, status, req, xml, xmlHttpRequest, responseXML) {
            alert('success' + status + ">>" +typeof $(req.responseXML));
            var myObj = new Array();
            $(req.responseXML)
             .find('GetWeatherResult')
                    .each(function(){
                        alert($(this));
                      myObj.push($(this)); 

                    });
            $(myObj).each(function(){
                var x = $(this).find('Location').text();
                alert('loc'+ x + $(this).find('Location'));
                var p = $(this).find('Location');
                for (var key in p) {
                        alert(key + " -> " + p[key]);
                    }
                });
        }

        function processError(data, status, req) {
            alert(req.responseText + " " + status);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(req);
        }  


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Weather Report
    </h3>
    Enter your city name:
    <input id="cityName" type="text" />
    <input id="btnCallWebService" value="GetInformation" type="button" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of null

Comment: The above code is working fine in browsers after disabling browser security...but it is not working in physical devices..and I'm getting XML response  is null..

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the cross domain calls to http://www.webservicex.net

See this post:
[Cordova 1.9.0 Ajax not retrieving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340082/cordova-1-9-0-ajax-not-retrieving)

Edit your xml in your res folder to include this line:

```
<access origin="http://www.webservicex.net*"/>
```

Or if its Phonegap-Build add that line to the config.xml